# st.file_uploader() Bytes type to png or jpg

Tags: python, image, byte, streamlit

I am using `st.file_uploader()` to do some image processing, I need to convert Bytes type to some `PIL.Image` type and them to a `numpy` array.

```
import streamlit as st
import PIL.Image as Image
import cv2

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("**Upload a Chest X-Ray Image**", type= ['png', 'jpg'] )
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # To read file as bytes:
    bytes_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
    st.image(bytes_data)
    # ReSize
    item = cv2.resize(bytes_data,dsize=(224,224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # ReScale Values
    item = item / 255
```

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit uploaded files are file-like objects, meaning they are not actual files, in that case you don't have total control of the file. In order to take absolute control of the file to be able to manipulate it as you wish, you will have to save the file to local disk. In your use-case I have constructed a function which will save the file in a directory called `uploadedImages` and then returns the path to that directory so we can fetch the image to be able to work with it.

I added `...` in my code snippet which represent the rest of your imports to keep the snippet short

```py
... 
import os

def get_image_path(img):
    # Create a directory and save the uploaded image.
    file_path = f"data/uploadedImages/{img.name}"
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(file_path), exist_ok=True)
    with open(file_path, "wb") as img_file:
        img_file.write(img.getbuffer())
    return file_path

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("**Upload a Chest X-Ray Image**", type= ['png', 'jpg'] )
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # Get actual image file
    bytes_data = get_image_path(uploaded_file)
    st.image(bytes_data)
    # ReSize
    item = cv2.resize(bytes_data,dsize=(224,224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    # ReScale Values
    item = item / 255
```

Answer (score 1):

The bytes you get represent a JPEG or PNG-encoded image. You can read them using pillow, matplotlib, or ImageIO. The latter supports file-like objects out-of-the-box, which avoids saving the file to disk which is slow. (Note: Pillow can do this, too, but ImageIO does it in one line.)

```py
import streamlit as st
import imageio.v3 as iio
import cv2

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("**Upload a Chest X-Ray Image**", type= ['png', 'jpg'] )
if uploaded_file is not None:
    # uploaded_file.seek(0)  # seek to start if needed

    # img is a numpy array using RGB colorspace
    img = iio.imread(uploaded_file)

    # consume img
    item = cv2.cvtcolor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    ...  # more processing
```

You may also be interested in taking a look at scikit-image, which does common image processing in python but uses RGB images (less complex mental model). It's heavily used by the bioinformatics community, so chances are you will be in good hands when dealing with x-ray images.